# Problems trying to do an LDAP search filter

Tags: search, filter, ldap, directory-server

I am trying to get a list of users in our LDAP server by way of an LDAP filter.

We have a custom object class called, say customuser, which we use instead of the user object class.

Our base dn is like the following:
`dc=somedomain,dc=edu`

So the dn for the group I am trying to list users of is:
`cn=staff,ou=group,dc=somedomain,dc=edu`

So I was thinking the filter would be like the following:
`(&(objectCategory=customuser) (memberOf=cn=staff,ou=group,dc=somedomain,dc=edu))`

However this filter does not work, it returns 0 entries.

Comment: To ensure these values are correct, can you check if  `(objectCategory=customuser)  memberOf` returns the `memberOf` attribute of all the users?

Comment: Does a filter of just: (objectCategory=customuser) return any entries?